# Nginx + PHP-FPM Error: This Page is Temporarily Unavailble

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, php, raspbian

I am trying to setup a Nginx / PHP-FPM server on my raspberry Pi (Debian) and I am having trouble getting the php to work correctly.

Text displayed on webpage: This Page is Temporarily Unavailble

I have checked the nginx logs and there are no errors being recorded.

This is my nginx.conf:

```
#   Pi Nginx Config v0.1 10:53 30/01/2014
#   NOTE: fastcgi is NOT php5-fpm

server {
    listen 1080;
    #       server_name mysite.org;
    charset utf-8;
    access_log off;
    root /var/www/cms;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files       $uri $uri/ /index.php?id=$uri&$args;
    }

   location ~* /admin/.*\.php$ {
        try_files $uri /admin/index.php?id=$uri&$args;      # Try the admin index page
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
   }        



    location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;        # Try any .php files in root or throw a 404
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        expires 2h;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:ico|js|gif|jpg|png)$ {
        expires 14d;
    }

    location ~* \.(htm|css|html)$ {
        expires 2d;
    }

# this blocks direct access to the XML files (but sitemap.xml) - that hold all the data
    location ~* \.xml$           { deny all; }
location ~* \.xml\.bak$     { deny all; }
    location = /sitemap.xml { allow all; }

# this prevents hidden files (beginning with a period) from being served
    location ~ /\.          { deny all; }
    location ^~ /uploads/ {
    if ($request_uri ~* \.php$) {return 403;}
    }
}
```

I do not have enough experience to see anything wrong with this config. My server is on port 1080 and the server root is within the cms directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check error log, inside `/var/logs/nginx`

Comment: I have done, There are no errors being logged.

Comment: maybe because u didn't define a logger, add `error_log '/var/log/nginx/error.log` below the access log